# uanable to run java -jar command from jenkins pipeline

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, jenkins

Am new to Devops role & facing  issue while executing `java -jar <jar-name>` command through jenkins pipeline code, I cloned a git lab repo & executed maven commands `mvn clean install`  to create jar file & it is sucess, I entered in to target directory & tried to execute  `java -jar <jar-name>`  & here, the pipeline is not moving farward & getting hanged, can any one help me to solve this issue please.
here is my code:

```
sh ''' + cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Exf-Fhir/fhirkafka/exf-fhirServerV1/target/
+ java -jar exf-fhirServerV1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -itd
'''
```

Comment: Can you try setting full path of java like :      sh ''' + cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Exf-Fhir/fhirkafka/exf-fhirServerV1/target/
+ /usr/bin/java -jar exf-fhirServerV1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -itd
'''

Comment: Tried but no use